# Lcmm and pooling multiple imputed datasets

Tags: imputation

I am working in R. I have 5 imputed datasets that I would like to pool the results of. My original analysis in jointlcmm - similar to syntax in lcmm - does anyone know how I can pool the results from jlcmm or lcmm to produce one result?